# Send a raw ethernet packet from inside a kernel module

Tags: c, sockets, linux-kernel, network-programming, raw-sockets

I found out that I need to build a new `sk_buff` struct in the kernel module and pass it to my network device, but what I can't figure out is how to set the struct variables for a simple raw ethernet packet.

This has to be easy, but I would really appreciate it, if someone could give me a sample code of how to put the `sk_buff` together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the function `packet_sendmsg_spkt` in `net/packet/af_packet.c` for inspiration.  The hard part is getting a `struct sock` if you don't have a socket...

**Edit:** Added a basic code shell:

```
int sendpacket(struct socket *sock, struct net_device *dev, __be16 proto, void *data, size_t len)
{
    struct sock *sk = sock->sk;
    struct sk_buff *skb;

    if (!(dev->flags & IFF_UP))
        return -ENETDOWN;

    if (len > dev->mtu + dev->hard_header_len)
        return -EMSGSIZE;

    skb = sock_wmalloc(sk, len + LL_RESERVED_SPACE(dev), 0, GFP_KERNEL);

    if (skb == NULL)
        return -ENOBUFS;

    /* FIXME: Save some space for broken drivers that write a
     * hard header at transmission time by themselves. PPP is the
     * notable one here. This should really be fixed at the driver level.
     */
    skb_reserve(skb, LL_RESERVED_SPACE(dev));
    skb_reset_network_header(skb);

    /* Try to align data part correctly */
    if (dev->header_ops) {
        skb->data -= dev->hard_header_len;
        skb->tail -= dev->hard_header_len;
        if (len < dev->hard_header_len)
            skb_reset_network_header(skb);
    }

    memcpy(skb_put(skb, len), data, len);
    skb->protocol = proto;
    skb->dev = dev;
    skb->priority = sk->sk_priority;

    dev_queue_xmit(skb);

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Any thoughts on how to obtain a socket?